# End .FindNext wrapping without a loop?

Tags: excel, vba

I am a vba beginner and am building a CRM spreadsheet for a small company. I have a worksheet with company/customer names and I am trying to pull their contact information from another worksheet and show it in a pop-up userform.

My userform lists individual contact information with textboxes, so I am using the .Find/FindNext functions to populate them. But the FindNext keeps wrapping back to the beginning, causing the userform to show the same names again.

How do I stop .FindNext from wrapping without using a loop?

I've tried putting it in a Do-Loop, but that seems to put it in an infinite loop or something and freezes excel. I've also tried a LastRow formula with no luck.

```
Sub UserForm_Activate()

Dim fSearch As Range 'the column we are searching in
Dim fFind As Range 'the value we are searching for
Dim LastRow As Long

Set fSearch = Sheets("Contact List").Range("Company_Find")

'First Find
Set fFind = fSearch.Find(What:=Selection.Value)
Debug.Print
    Txt_Contact1 = fFind.Offset(0, 5)
    Txt_Title1 = fFind.Offset(0, -1)
    Txt_Email1 = fFind.Offset(0, 1)
    Txt_Office1 = fFind.Offset(0, 2)
    Txt_Mobile1 = fFind.Offset(0, 3)

'Second Find
Set fFind = fSearch.FindNext(fFind)
Debug.Print
    Txt_Contact2 = fFind.Offset(0, 5)
    Txt_Title2 = fFind.Offset(0, -1)
    Txt_Email2 = fFind.Offset(0, 1)
    Txt_Office2 = fFind.Offset(0, 2)
    Txt_Mobile2 = fFind.Offset(0, 3)

'Third Find
Set fFind = fSearch.FindNext(fFind)
Debug.Print
    Txt_Contact3 = fFind.Offset(0, 5)
    Txt_Title3 = fFind.Offset(0, -1)
    Txt_Email3 = fFind.Offset(0, 1)
    Txt_Office3 = fFind.Offset(0, 2)
    Txt_Mobile3 = fFind.Offset(0, 3)

'Fourth Find

'Fifth Find

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Set fFind = fSearch.Find(What:=Selection.Value)
    If Not fFind Is Nothing Then
        'Save the address of the first found range to compare with later
        Fadd = fFind.Address
    End If

    Do While Not fFind Is Nothing
         'Do stuff

         Set fFind = fSearch.FindNext(fFind)
         If Not fFind is Nothing Then
             'If the next found address is the same as the first, stop searching, exit the loop
             If fFind.Address = Fadd Then Exit Do
         End If
    Loop
```

This is my method. Hope it helps. I reckon you did not properly exit your `Do...Loop`, hence the infinite loops that killed Excel.
This loop will exit, unless you change the value of the first found range.

You are far better off using a loop then to write a Find method for each time you'll have to search. This results in a hard coded finding "loop" with no flexibility in iterations.

**EDIT**

The code below will loop to fill all textboxes in a `UF`, and exit the loop once all are filled/no new values are being found

```
Dim ctrl as Control
Dim b as Integer

Set fFind = fSearch.Find(What:=Selection.Value)
If Not fFind Is Nothing Then
    b = 1
    'Save the address of the first found range to compare with later
    Fadd = fFind.Address
End If

Do While Not fFind Is Nothing
     For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
         If ctrl.Name Like "Txt_Contact" & b And ctrl.Value = "" Then ctrl.Value = fFind.Offset(0, 5)
         If ctrl.Name Like "Txt_Title" & b And ctrl.Value = "" Then ctrl.Value = fFind.Offset(0, -1)
         If ctrl.Name Like "Txt_Email" & b And ctrl.Value = "" Then ctrl.Value = fFind.Offset(0, 1)
         If ctrl.Name Like "Txt_Office" & b And ctrl.Value = "" Then ctrl.Value = fFind.Offset(0, 2)
         If ctrl.Name Like "Txt_Mobile" & b And ctrl.Value = "" Then ctrl.Value = fFind.Offset(0, 3)
     Next ctrl

     Set fFind = fSearch.FindNext(fFind)
     If Not fFind is Nothing Then
         'If the next found address is the same as the first, stop searching, exit the loop
         If fFind.Address = Fadd Then Exit Do
     End If
     b = b + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Thank you Tim, your suggestion did help with the infinite loop! But I'm still trying to figure out how to end the search when there are no unique values left. 

Do you have any suggestions on how to end the FindNext search when all new finds have been exhausted? My userform has the ability to hold 5 search values, but if there are less than 5 found in the search then they repeat, filling up all 5 spaces. Thank you!

Comment: I have added a piece of code to my answer. Hope this helps @CFWalker. Note that if the number of finds exceeds the number of textboxes, these finds will be excluded

Comment: This looks like it should work, but I keep getting the error: "Object does not support this property or method" on the ```If ctrl.Name``` lines. I'm not too familiar with control functions. Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh, I figured out  using ```If ctrl.Name Like "Txt_Contact" & b = True Then ctrl.Value = fFind.Offset(0, 5)``` works. Thank you Tim!!