# Loop search text for same row specific range columns and once found, return value in a different row but same column

Tags: excel, vba, loops, search

I am new to VBA and need some help to come up a code to solve this. eg. I want to loop search column B to H in each row and return a specific cell value.

eg. loop search Column B to H for row 7 and once "p20028" cell (E7) is located based on column J. Return/copy "sa2084" at D5 to cell I7.

[image]

```
Sub whereused()
    Dim part_num_1 As String        
    Dim finalrow As Integer        
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim column As integer

    finalrow = Sheet("Sheet1").Range("J1400").End(x1up).row

    For row = 3 To finalrow        
        For column = 1 To 8        
            part_num = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, 10).Value        
            If Cells(row, column).Value = part_num Then

            End If        
        Next column            
    Next row    
End Sub
```

Comment: Use [.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) instead. I see no use of looping through all cells trying to find a single value. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55587020/10540017) is an example of a Find loop

Comment: Some notes: First you need to specify a sheet for `If Cells(row, column)` otherwise Excel cannot know in which sheet these cells are. • Secondly there is a typo in `x1up` it has to be `xlup` after the `x` there is a lower case `L` not a  one! I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit` to avoid such typos: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*. • Finally your row counting variables need to be declared as `Long` because Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle.

Comment: Still having trouble getting it right. I want the macro to return I4=sa75000; I5=sa2085; I6=sa2084; I7=sa2084; I8=sa2084. This long data is a structural bill of material and using concatenate function gets parts in different columns to the same column; however, would like to have a column (eg. column I ) to return where the parts being used on the sub-assembly level. Can anyone please refer me a sample code to a similar case for me to study? thanks

Comment: Actually we cannot provide samples here. We can only assist you to fix your code on your own, but your question is very unclear (actually you didn't ask a question yet). Please be much more precise. All the information that belongs to your question should be within the question part (not in comments). Also we need to know what is wrong with your code. Where did you get errors and which or what did your code do vs what did you expect. Please also [edit] your question and update the code to what you actually have (including the fixes I suggested) already.